# Stacked bar plot with explicit axis domain

Tags: pgfplots, bar-chart, nodes-near-coords

I have a data table which contains positive and negative values for different categories (columns) as input. I want to visualize these values by a stacked bar plot, which shows a stacked bar plot for all negative values to the left and all positive values as a stacked bar to the right. I already found out that I cannot do this with a single axis environment, as `xbar stacked` does not render correctly (at least not as I want it) if positive and negative values are added to the same stack.
Therefore, I am trying to apply a strategy that I found here: [stacking negative value for ybar](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/109887/stacking-negative-value-for-ybar), which uses two axis environments with the same range for the x-axes. I started with the positive bars by filtering out negative values read from the data table. This works as expected, as long as I do not specify `xmin` and `xmax` for that axis. If I do so, the output is looking weird and not explainable for me.

Here is a simple example of my current tries:

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\pgfplotstableread{
Year    Cat1  Cat2    Cat3   Cat4
2005    10     50      -10     30  
2006    -40     60      -15     90
2007    -20     60      -15     60
}\mytable

\begin{document}%

  % First try: use negative and positive values in the same axis environment - FAIL
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
      xbar stacked,
      ]
      \addplot table [x index=1,y expr=\coordindex] {\mytable};
      \addplot table [x index=2,y expr=\coordindex] {\mytable};
      \addplot table [x index=3,y expr=\coordindex] {\mytable};
      \addplot table [x index=4,y expr=\coordindex] {\mytable};
      \legend{Cat1,Cat2,Cat3,Cat4}
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}

  % Second try: only draw positive values into single axis environment - SUCCESS, but drawing of negative values is missing
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
      xbar stacked,
      restrict x to domain*=0:,
      ]
      \addplot table [x index=1,y expr=\coordindex] {\mytable};
      \addplot table [x index=2,y expr=\coordindex] {\mytable};
      \addplot table [x index=3,y expr=\coordindex] {\mytable};
      \addplot table [x index=4,y expr=\coordindex] {\mytable};
      \legend{Cat1,Cat2,Cat3,Cat4}
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}

  % Third try: explicitly defining the x-axis range to center the zero point - FAILS
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
      xbar stacked,
      restrict x to domain*=0:,
      xmin=-200, xmax=200,  % <-- only difference to second try (above)
      ]
      \addplot table [x index=1,y expr=\coordindex] {\mytable};
      \addplot table [x index=2,y expr=\coordindex] {\mytable};
      \addplot table [x index=3,y expr=\coordindex] {\mytable};
      \addplot table [x index=4,y expr=\coordindex] {\mytable};
      \legend{Cat1,Cat2,Cat3,Cat4}
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

This piece of code results in the following output:
[image: Result of the above LaTeX code]

Does anybody have a working solution for this problem or at least an explanation why the definition of `xmin` and `xmax` changes the produced output and does not only define the axis range (as the command implies)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In PGFPlots v1.13 your example now works with the new key `stack negative=separate`. Here the full code, which can also be found in the manual in the section 4.5.9 on page 99.

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
    \pgfplotsset{compat=1.13}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \pgfplotstableread{
            Year Cat1 Cat2 Cat3 Cat4
            2005 10 50 -10 30
            2006 -40 60 -15 90
            2007 -20 60 -15 60
        }\mytable
        \begin{axis}[
            xbar stacked,
            % is default anyway:
            stack negative=separate,
            %
            /pgf/number format/1000 sep=,
            xmajorgrids,
            nodes near coords,
            nodes near coords style={font=\tiny},
            ytick distance=1,
            legend style={
                at={(0.5,-0.1)},
                anchor=north,legend
                columns=-1,
            },
            extra x ticks={0},
            extra x tick style={
                grid style={black},
                xticklabel=\empty,
            },
        ]
            \addplot table [x index=1,y=Year] {\mytable};
            \addplot table [x index=2,y=Year] {\mytable};
            \addplot table [x index=3,y=Year] {\mytable};
            \addplot table [x index=4,y=Year] {\mytable};
            \legend{Cat1,Cat2,Cat3,Cat4}
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing result of above code]

Answer (score 4):

Maybe you can use a `groupplot` with `horizontal sep=0pt` to get

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}

\pgfplotstableread{
Year    Cat1  Cat2    Cat3   Cat4
2005    10     50      -10     30  
2006    -40     60      -15     90
2007    -20     60      -15     60
}\mytable

\begin{document}%
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{groupplot}[
      group style={
        group size = 2 by 1,
        horizontal sep=0pt,
        yticklabels at=edge left,
        },
      xbar stacked,
      ytick=data,
      yticklabel style={/pgf/number format/1000 sep=},
      scale only axis,
      height=5.7cm,
      width=3.7cm
    ]
    \nextgroupplot[
        xmin=-200,xmax=0,
        xtick={-200,-100},
        axis y line*=left,
        restrict x to domain*=:0,
      ]
      \pgfplotsinvokeforeach{1,...,4}{%
        \addplot table [x index=#1,y index=0] {\mytable};%
      }
    \nextgroupplot[
        xmin=0,xmax=200,
        xtick={0,100,200},
        axis y line*=right,
        restrict x to domain*=0:,
      ]
      \pgfplotsinvokeforeach{1,...,4}{%
        \addplot table [x index=#1,y index=0] {\mytable};%
      }
      \legend{Cat1,Cat2,Cat3,Cat4}
  \end{groupplot}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

or

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}

\pgfplotstableread{
Year    Cat1  Cat2    Cat3   Cat4
2005    10     50      -10     30  
2006    -40     60      -15     90
2007    -20     60      -15     60
}\mytable

\begin{document}%
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{groupplot}[
      group style={
        group size = 2 by 1,
        horizontal sep=0pt,
        yticklabels at=edge left,
        },
      xbar stacked,
      ytick=data,
      yticklabel style={/pgf/number format/1000 sep=},
      enlarge y limits=0.25,
      scale only axis,
      height=5.7cm
    ]
    \nextgroupplot[
        xmin=-100,xmax=0,width=2.5cm,
        xtick={-100,-50},
        axis y line*=left,
        restrict x to domain*=:0,
      ]
      \pgfplotsinvokeforeach{1,...,4}{%
        \addplot table [x index=#1,y index=0] {\mytable};%
      }
    \nextgroupplot[
        xmin=0,xmax=200,width=5cm,
        xtick={0,50,...,200},
        axis y line*=right,
        restrict x to domain*=0:,
      ]
      \pgfplotsinvokeforeach{1,...,4}{%
        \addplot table [x index=#1,y index=0] {\mytable};%
      }
      \legend{Cat1,Cat2,Cat3,Cat4}
  \end{groupplot}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is another workaround to the described problem. By adding `disabledatascaling` to the list of axis parameters, the weird behavior is gone. Unfortunately, this does not work in case of numbers larger than +/- 16,000 and in case of very small floating point numbers, but for many other cases it works.
Here is the resulting source code:

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}


\pgfplotstableread{
Year    Cat1  Cat2    Cat3   Cat4
2005    10.0     50.0      -40.0     30.0
2006    -40.0     60.0      -40.0     90.0
2007    60.0     -40.0      -40.0     60.0
}\mytable

\begin{document}%

  % Fourth try: explicitly defining the x-axis range to center the zero point, separate axis for positive and negative values
  \begin{tikzpicture}

    \begin{axis}[
      xbar stacked,
      restrict x to domain*=0:,
      xmin=-200, xmax=200,
      disabledatascaling,  % <-- this is important
      ]
      \addplot table [x index=1,y expr=\coordindex] {\mytable};
      \addplot table [x index=2,y expr=\coordindex] {\mytable};
      \addplot table [x index=3,y expr=\coordindex] {\mytable};
      \addplot table [x index=4,y expr=\coordindex] {\mytable};
      \legend{Cat1,Cat2,Cat3,Cat4}

    \end{axis}

    \begin{axis}[
      xbar stacked,
      restrict x to domain*=:0,
      xmin=-200, xmax=200,
      xtick=\empty,
      ytick=\empty,
      axis x line=none,
      axis y line=none,
      disabledatascaling,  % <-- this is important
      ]
      \addplot table [x index=1,y expr=\coordindex] {\mytable};
      \addplot table [x index=2,y expr=\coordindex] {\mytable};
      \addplot table [x index=3,y expr=\coordindex] {\mytable};
      \addplot table [x index=4,y expr=\coordindex] {\mytable};
      \legend{Cat1,Cat2,Cat3,Cat4}

    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Using this, the following graph is produced:
[image: Resulting graph using the described workaround]